# Can't use Windows Explorer after killing it with Task manager and running it again

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, task-manager

I'm used to kill `explorer.exe` for whatever reasons with `Task Manager`. For years it caused no problems at all. However I've installed new `Windows 7` on new `SSD`, updated the system etc; and now when I kill explorer and run it again (with `Task Manager` too) it starts, but I can't use it because the error dialog popups with following message: `The remote procedure call failed and did not execute` and it stays that way until next PC restart. How to solve this except for not killing it or restarting PC every time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once. I resolved it by typing `Services` into the start menu search, scrolling to "Remote Procedure Call" and setting it to *Automatic* startup.

Comment: Already done it, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that the “Remote Procedure Call” service is not running at that time.
Run “services.msc” then check “Remote Procedure Call” service’s status, ensure its startup type is configured as “automatic”.

Configure “RPC Locator” to "Manual".

Best regards,
Joy.